# Dependency of a matrix in device

Tags: cuda

I have to calculate the elements of a matrix (see picture below for a `6*8` example). The matrix elements have dependencies, so that the value of `t1` must be computed first, then that `t2`, which depends on `t1`, than that of `t3`, which depends on `t2` values, and so on.

How to calculate the matrix elements in CUDA? Should I use only one kernel call and compute all the values with the help of `____syncthreads()` or should the calculations of the matrix elements in minor diagonals be performed in separate kernels?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have described it, the logical approach would be to launch a separate kernel for each stage of the calculation. In a non-trivially sized problem, the "computational front" will grow in size rapidly, so that some degree of computational efficiency can be obtained as the solution propagates across the domain.

The "best" method is probably not to sweep across the domain, but rather to solve the *whole domain* iteratively until the solution converges.  [Jeong and Whittaker](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.164.816) published a very good paper on an iterative label correcting method for solving the stationary Eikonal equation (which is a classic upwind sweeping calculation similar to your matrix picture). In their approach, a computational grid is decomposed into blocks and each block containing values which have not converged are recomputed until it converges. When a characteristic crosses a sub block boundary, any values which depend on a changed value are relabelled as unconverged and the process continues until the whole domain converges.

You can see a Youtube video of this algorithm in action on a CUDA GPU [here](http://youtu.be/b4p_C7I4zIs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use same kernel to compute t1 values then t2 values based on t1 and so on. This kernel can be called recursively to operate on different values depending on some parameters passed to it.

If the elements in t1 are not dependent on each other then there is no need to use __syncthreads() inside the kernel, as there is an implicit barrier after every kernel call.

However if they are dependent you have to use __syncthreads() in the kernel call.